# CSS: How do I change where the UI loads for my user?

Tags: html, css

My question is somewhat broad - I am trying to allow the user to navigate my site using their arrow keys. So, when the user presses the up arrow from the landing page, a separate screen from the top will slide into the user's view.

My current approach is to create a view for each of these different pages (landing, top, bottom, left, right), and make their positions relative and slide them to different areas of the browser using commands like left: -100% etc. I would make the overflow of the landing page hidden so the user would not be able to navigate to the other areas of the page without using the arrow keys.

However, as I am trying to move the locations of these pages, they don't seem to comply because the landing page always loads at the top left, and I cannot seem to reposition where my page lands. Is there any way for me to make it so that when the user loads my page, his view point lands at a screen that has been shifted using say the top/left commands?

Comment: Why not just make separate div elements that hide/show on the button click of Up, Down, Left, Right?

Comment: I'm trying my approach because it allows for a smoother transition once I add some JS functionality

Comment: Hide/Show different views then. I said div elements since you used the html tag. Have a landing view that renders onload, having onclick events to hide the landing view and display the other views.